# Append to file outside external storage default folder in Android

Tags: android, file, append, text-files

I want to build a `TXT` file and add new lines to it every time.
I don't want it to be in the app `data` folder in external storage (default folder used in `openFileOutput()`) since it's erased as the app uninstalled (This is a log meant for these issues).
How can it be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FileWriter`. The constructor's second argument defines whether an existing file should be opened and appended.

```
FileWriter writer;
try {
    writer = new FileWriter(yourFilePathHere, true);
    writer.write("Hello World");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    //Error handling
}
```

`yourFilePathHere` might be `new File(getExternalStorageDirectory(), "log.txt").getAbsolutePath()`;